# CakePHP unable to write to certain files

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am starting to develop a website using CakePHP for my framework, I've literally just started and have already encountered errors, I can't work about what they mean.

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 310
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 310
Warning: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 320
Warning: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/cache/models/ is not writable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 320
Warning: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/cache/ is not writable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 320
```

I am also getting an error about the following:

```
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/Config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application [CORE/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php, line 717]
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in app/Config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to your application [CORE/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php, line 721]
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'file_map' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 310]
```

Any help would be much appreciated by all.

Comment: `app/tmp` needs to be writable by the user your web server runs as.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Wooble points out the app/tmp folder needs to be writeable by your webserver user.

To correct the other two errors you should edit the app/Config/core.php file as suggested in the errors.  Cake ships with default values which should be changed so that not every Cake project has the same security values.  If you open that file you will see instructions in the comments.

If you're new to Cake then have a look at the tutorial on the manual site http://book.cakephp.org ...

Comment: Thank you very much, was actually so simple! Much appreciated good sir!

Comment: Hi yeah I accepted the one above, I can't expect both answers, but I'll expect the last one that you commented! again thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you has folder: app/tmp/

and have the sub folder structure like:

tmp/

--/cache

--/logs

--/sessions

--/tests

Then, check the web users' permission on these folder.

Answer (score 2):

This directory: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/evolvidsnew/app/tmp/cache` needs to be made writeable by whatever user ID your webserver is running under. You don't specify which OS you're on, so can't tell you how to do that specifically.

Comment: Brillant that worked I made the folders writeable, however I still have the following error 
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in app/Config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application [CORE/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php, line 717]
Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in app/Config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to your application [CORE/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php, line 721]
Im also using Mac OS X Lion latest version. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

go to your APPLICATION_PATH/app/config/core.php file.
and  find the "Security.salt" and 'Security.cipherSeed' .
after that please change the value of both.
then you will get solution.