# Cakephp Warning 512 cache folder unable to write

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, file-permissions

I am having a problem with troubleshooting this:

I am getting this kind of warning on my website suddenly, it never happened and I tried to solve it by following various methods i found over the internet.

```
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 325]
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'debug_kit_en-us' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 325]
```

I have tried:

1. chmod -R 777 tmp
2. Delete the tmp folder and then recreate it with its subdirectories.
3. Delete the tmp folder and upload a fresh tmp folder from a fresh cakephp folder.
4. Already run whoami php script and already made sure the folder belong to that user.
5. I tried to reboot the server.

Cakephp version : 2.4.5

Server OS: Centos 6.5

PHP Version 5.3.3

Apache version: Apache/2.2.15

I have tried most of the solutions from stack overflow and other places but no luck so far. Could it be an issue with my server configuration or from cakephp it self?
If my question is still unclear, please feel free to request more clarification.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: May be this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879614/facing-a-file-permission-error-while-running-cakephp-in-ubuntu-10-4

Comment: There isn't enough information here to say without guessing what the specific cause is (showing the output of `cd tmp/cache/persistent; ls -la` would) but this question has been asked so many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP unable to write to certain files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379899/cakephp-unable-to-write-to-certain-files)

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions proposed by various links online, we found that none of those solutions worked for us.

Finally, after couple of hours of head banging, we realized that the issue in our case is not related to permissions. In fact it was because the system has used up 100% of the allocated disk space. Removing files and freeing up some space from our disk actually resolved the issue.

Comment: If there was no free space it's hard to believe this was the only problem encountered =)